# Can I use singleton lifetime for a GraphServiceClient instance?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am building a C# asp.net core WebApi that has access to all users' data.

Can I add GraphServiceClient  to aspnet core service dependency injection as Singleton lifespan? Is it thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GraphServiceClient` object is thread-safe and re-entrant. `GraphServiceClient` class handles building requests, sending them to the Graph API, and processing the responses.

I'm using `GraphServiceClient` as singleton in several web API applications and I've never encountered the issue.

You are free to re-use the client or create a new instance on each call. It is really up to how you want to manage the client instances.

Comment: Thank you for help. Do you know any reference to Microsoft documentation stating that it is thread safe? I searched and I received conflicting information.

Comment: It's based on the experience. It of course depends on your use case and version of sdk. I've been using v4 for years without issue. For v5 I can try to create a test. It would be useful to hear the experience from other developers.